# Flex space-between - evenly distributed over multiple line

Tags: css, flexbox

Codepen example: [here](https://codepen.io/nclsvh/pen/eGKBrG)

**Is it possible to rearange items in a flex-container with `justify-content: space-between` evenly over multiple lines?**

As you can see in the codepen ([link](https://codepen.io/nclsvh/pen/eGKBrG)) most items are on the top row, and only those that don't fit that row are displayed on the second line (with space-between).

!! Note that I only made the div containing all filters a set width to show in the codepen. It will be a 80% width of a bootstrap col-12. So on large they fit on one row, on md I want to make sure there is not just 1 item on the second line, but that the whole group of filters centers and evenly distributes over 2 rows (seem included image).

I would like to have it so that there are 4 or 5 items on the top row, and 4 or 5 on the bottom row.
I hope the image explains more:
[image]

Thanks for the help, pretty new to flex!

Comment: simply add some margin to `.filters .filter` make it `margin: 5px 10px;`

Comment: I should have made clear that the width is not set (as in my codepen, I set it there to replicate the items displaying on 2 lines). On a wide desktop all items fit on one line, not when you make the screen smaller. I will update my question to make this more clear.

Comment: @TemaniAfif doing that the following line would not be aligned on the center. Change the `.filters .filter` and give it some margin to right and left, also, change the justify-content from `.filters` to center.

Comment: @Cheshire thanks for the suggestion, but doesn't seem to change much for me (in my codepen in chrome).

Comment: @Cheshire ah, I think I understand now. This indeed did the trick, although margins around the items are set now, but it looks way better anyhow: https://codepen.io/nclsvh/pen/VMdPgj

Comment: @nclsvh nice to hear that you think you got it solved =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Cheshire's suggestions in the comments, I found a way to make it work, more or less.

If you add `margin-right` and `margin-left` to the items and set `justify-content: center` you can achieve what I was looking for.
The only drawback is that you have to set a fixed margin (left and right) to the items, so you can't use `space-between` anymore. But in my case it still looks better though.