# How Can I Force Items To Stay In Line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to style a section with a title and a button below and want the buttons to stay perfectly in line no matter the browser size (unless on mobile in which case they stack).
Due to the fact that there is more text in one title than the other, when I change screen size some of the titles go from one line to needing to use two lines forcing the button to go lower on the page while the other button stays.

[image]

I have the items in flex boxes but is there a way to maybe force them to stay inline with each other?

### -

EDIT:

What I tried most recently was removing the buttons and putting them within their own section below.

I also tried this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682492/flex-space-between-evenly-distributed-over-multiple-line) by targeting the new section id, no success.

This is my original code with the problem.

```css
/* Section: Clients */

#clients .items {
  display: flex;
}

#clients .items img {
  display: block;
  position: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

#clients .cr {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 29%;
  max-width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#clients .cr-last {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 29%;
  max-width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#clients .client-r {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

#clients .cr-btn {
  background-color: #4C9FCF;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Section: Client Resources -->
<section id="clients" class="py-1">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="m-heading text-center">
      <span id="client-r" class="text-primary">Client</span> Resources
    </h2>
    <div class="items py-1">
      <div class="cr">
        <h2>
          TD Ameritrade Access
          <p></p>
        </h2>
        <button class="cr-btn">LOGIN</button>
      </div>
      <div class="cr">
        <h2>
          American Equity Access
          <p></p>
          <button class="cr-btn">LOGIN</button>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="cr-last">
        <h2>
          American Equity Access
          <p></p>
          <button class="cr-btn">LOGIN</button>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin-top: auto;` to the buttons. That will force them to the bottom of the flexbox.

Since there's no code, it's hard to know if this solution will work properly and makes some assumptions about your code.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 33.33333%;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.button {
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: auto; /* This is the magic. */
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="card">
    <h2>Title Short</h2>
    <div class="button">Button</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <h2>Title Long Title Long Title Long</h2>
    <div class="button">Button</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <h2>Title Short</h2>
    <div class="button">Button</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to achieve can be done with the `flex-wrap` property. You'd want to set its value to `nowrap`.

```css
flex-wrap: nowrap
```

You can read more about it on MDN's documentation site, found in the link below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

Answer (score 0):

An inline-block tag like

```
<div>
<div id="div1" style="display: inline-block">Content1</div>
<div id="div2" style="display: inline-block">Content2</div>
</div>
```

should usually force the two divs next-to each other.  Without seeing/trying your actual code, it's hard to say exactly how to do it regarding your mobile requirements.  There is a meta-tag for viewport like the following which takes care of a lot of mobile styling issues:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

If this is not what you intend as the result, what would you actually like the divs to do when the screen is too small?  Should one of them disappear? Also, you may have some other styles on your page that are causing extra space (margins, padding, other divs orother elements) that may cause some extra whitespace that you're not expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Do this on your elements,

display: inline-block;

This will stick them together and line them up.

Answer (score 0):

**Responsive solution**

Another solution is add `flex-direction: row` and `justify-content: center` to your `#clients .items` element, in order to make it relative to the window width.

Your `#clients .items` element css should loks like below:

```
#clients .items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

And in your `#clients .cr` just add `width: 100%` and remove `max-width: 30%`. After that and your element css will be like below:

```
#clients .cr {
  position: relative;
  /* min-width:29%; */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

And your elements will be responsive too.

I made a JSFiddle: [The JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/b5ocjx8u/36/)